# How to display seconds in the taskbar clock?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, clock

Is it possible to get the Windows 7 taskbar clock to display the seconds, without having to install a utility?

Comment: It doesn't appear that can be done without a 3rd party app. Would a clock gadget work for you? Those display seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not currently possible without using third party apps. While windows allows you to change the short-form and long-form of your default times (`Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Additional Settings -> Time -> Short: hh:mm:ss tt`), this change does not take effect on the taskbar clock.

As @CharlieRB noted, you can use the Clock gadget to display the clock on your desktop, or you can click on the time to see an expanded calendar/clock flyout with the time in seconds.

Answer (score 18):

Currently it's not possible to make **Windows 7 taskbar clock** display the **seconds** without 3rd party app.

However, **7+ Taskbar Tweaker** from http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker adds this functionality with one single click:

[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker]

[image: Taskbar clock showing seconds]

Comment: Scott, what are you talking about? 7+ Taskbar Tweaker doesn't contain a virus. I've been personally using this software for a couple of years without any issues. Here's Virus Total scan log of the latest stable and beta setup versions of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker. Stable version setup .exe detect ratio 2 / 55 https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/93bf63beedb20c031f22951457e05e6790da02d80dc385b4df8866e1f881e2ae/analysis/1436611756 . Beta version setup .exe detect ratio 0 / 55 https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/294fbc3d566ef0d83dc687fe9b5c8d7cc54032bb365e7f42fa3c89ac9a054e2a/analysis/1436611775

Comment: could you try this, a popular anti-virus app in China: http://www.duba.net/

Comment: hmm, seems all chinese anti-virus tools think this software contains virus...

Comment: Yes, Scott. Thank you for letting us know. It's interesting that Chinese antivirus software marks 7+ taskbar tweaker as a virus. However, I choose to trust common sense, my own experience, Virus Total scan and Softpedia: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/7-Taskbar-Tweaker.shtml

Comment: i've installed this tool, it is very convenient, thanks.

Comment: Already had this installed - why didn't I spot this sooner? Marvellous. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Windows 10 build 14393:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ShowSecondsInSystemClock"=dword:00000001
```

In order to apply change immediately restart `explorer.exe` process via Task Manager.

Or relogin. Thanks to Microsoft. On Linux I use `xclock -digit` for 10 years ))

- http://winaero.com/blog/taskbar-clock-show-seconds-windows-10/
- http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/show-seconds-taskbar-clock-showsecondsinsystemclock/

Comment: Ah, wonderful.  I followed a guide that provided the registry key, but it didn't work until I restarted Explorer.  I was guessing I'd need to reboot, but simply restarting Explorer was far more convenient.  Thank you for a good write-up.

Comment: just to confirm (since the question specified Windows 7), this isn't applicable to Windows 7 is it?

Comment: @Michael Windows 7 **end of life**: January 14, 2020.((

Comment: haha yeah well end of life is just a Microsoft advisory, I still have a remote VM running it and having the seconds displayed compactly in the task bar would be perfect for seeing when my connection is lagging or hung...

Answer (score 2):

First, right-click on the clock and open Adjust date/time. Then go to Formats -> Change Date/Time Formats. Make sure you set the appropriate Long time format.

Then, add the following DWORD registry value to the registry path of `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] ShowSecondsInSystemClock` (set a hexadecimal value of 1).

Select explorer.exe from task manager->details tab and delete. Then go to menu New->Run and re-run explorer.exe

You should now see the long time format (eg. HH:mm:ss) displayed on your taskbar instead of the standard time.

Comment: This only seems to work on Windows 10.

Comment: In addition to the registry path, showing how to restart explorer.exe really helped.

Answer (score 0):

To add 100th seconds to the taskbar:

- Run `regedit`
- Go to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- Add a new DWord Value
- Rename it
  `ShowSecondsInSystemClock`
- Set the Hex Value to
  1
- Restart Computer

When you're logged in, the 100th second will be there!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PTBSync which does much more than only showing seconds in the trayclock.
It has a calendar with holidays of most contries in the world.
It has a converter for islam, jewish, coptic and iran calendars.
All this information can be displayed in a configurable tooltip when you hold the mouse over the trayclock. It can even make your taskbar transparent.
It runs on Windows XP up to Windows 10. It can also display the current weather and a flash clock with seconds on your desktop.

https://www.netcult.ch/elmue/ElmueSoft-en.htm

[image: PTBSync TrayClock]
[image: PTBSync Tooltip]